# Counting drop on an image

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I have image of drops and I want to calculate the number of it.

Here is the original image :
[image: Normal drops]

And Here after threshold application :
[image: Image ofter threshold]

i tried a lot of fonction on OpenCV and it's never right.

Do you have any ideas on how to do ?

Thanks

The best I got, was by using :
(img_morph is my binairized image)

```
rbc_bw = label(img_morph)
rbc_props = regionprops(rbc_bw)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 8))
ax.imshow(img_morph)
rbc_count = 0
for i, prop in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x.area > 250, rbc_props)):
    y1, x1, y2, x2 = (prop.bbox[0], prop.bbox[1],
                      prop.bbox[2], prop.bbox[3])
    width = x2 - x1
    height = y2 - y1
    r = plt.Rectangle((x1, y1), width = width, height=height,
                      color='b', fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(r)
    rbc_count += 1
print('Red Blood Cell Count:', rbc_count)
plt.show()
```

And all my circles are detected here but also the gap in between.
[image: Analysed]

A more difficult image :
[image]

Comment: As the cells you wish to count are apparently quite circular and consistently sized, you could maybe add a test of circularity and of size to filter your detected blobs.

Comment: Does it exist with the regionprop fonction ?

Comment: Errr... somebody removed the `import` statements so we can only guess which `regionprops` you are using, or look at the **OpenCV** tag you applied...

Comment: The regionprops is imported from skimage.measure

Comment: template matching would solve this trivially. they exhibit _some_ change of lighting direction relating to position but that shouldn't hurt too much. try TM_SQDIFF first but one of the other modes, with normalization, may perform better (not sqdiff normed, that's just scaling the score)

Comment: how would you like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp523.jpg (counting 761) only requires you to pick a template with an interactive rectangle selection -- please take the [tour]

Comment: It look amazing, but it's too much light dependant, and for this image no problem, but for some (I added a picture more difficult), it's hard to get something

Comment: can you do anything to prevent dim lighting, or is this what you _have to_ work with?

Comment: It's my material, the light is evolving, and some are more blurred than others, so, Ii'm not sure usnig a template will be the solution here.

Comment: well, this is the result for that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl2R6.jpg -- for dim images, just preprocess them to look less underexposed. that's what I did here. -- my approach only struggles with droplets of different sizes, even though it catches some of the deviants still

Comment: Really efficient, and how look your code for this ?

Comment: My first thought looking at your images was to try [Hough circles](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html)

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core idea: `matchTemplate`.

Approach:

- pick a template manually from the picture

  - histogram equalization for badly lit inputs (or always)
- `matchTemplate` with suitable matching mode

  - also using `copyMakeBorder` to catch instances clipping the border
- thresholding and non-maximum suppression

I'll skip the boring parts and use the first example input.

Manually picked template:

[image: template]

```
scores = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

Thresholding and NMS:

```
levelmask = (scores >= 0.3)

localmax = cv.dilate(scores, None, iterations=26)
localmax = (scores == localmax)

candidates = levelmask & localmax

(nlabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(candidates.astype(np.uint8), connectivity=8)
print(nlabels-1, "found") # background counted too
# and then draw a circle for each centroid except label 0
```

And that finds 766 instances. I see a few false negatives (missed) and saw a false positive too once, but that looks like less than 1%.

[image: output]

Comment: Nice. Might even use a second template for those stacked like in the top right like a tetraeder, if those occour more often. Would need to handle the rotation, though.

Comment: some overlap won't matter, already doesn't (my template is larger than one ball). a composite template would be a good idea however, to "average out" neighboring balls, get an ideal shape. -- overlapping balls don't cause overlapping detections because of the radius/iterations of the `dilate()`. choose it smaller to allow more overlap... that can let through some false detections near strong true detections. the absolute threshold should ideally discard false detections already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer because I was able towork on all my files :)

Comment: the complete notebook: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/e365d52e0ebf8a769e2f9539fdf46166